# Does casting to an int after std::floor guarantee the right result?

Tags: c++, math, floor

I'd like a `floor` function with the syntax

```
int floor(double x);
```

but `std::floor` returns a `double`. Is

```
static_cast <int> (std::floor(x));
```

guaranteed to give me the correct integer, or could I have an off-by-one problem? It seems to work, but I'd like to know for sure.

For bonus points, why the heck does `std::floor` return a `double` in the first place?

Comment: Jesse Beder is referring to how an integer is represented as a double and precautions to take about what happens when casting a double to int. For e.g., stackoverflow.com/a/9695341/1047213. It will be great if this point can be addressed in more detail.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The range of double is way greater than the range of 32 or 64 bit integers, which is why `std::floor` returns a `double`. Casting to `int` should be fine so long as it's within the appropriate range - but be aware that a `double` can't represent all 64 bit integers exactly, so you may also end up with errors when you go beyond the point at which the accuracy of `double` is such that the difference between two consecutive doubles is greater than 1.

Comment: So if it's in the right range, the cast is fine? Where does it say (something that implies) this in the spec?

Comment: Well, there are two operations here: std::floor, and the cast. std::floor is meant to return an integer, and the cast is specified in terms of an integer value. So long as std::floor returns a value which genuinely is an exact integer, I can't see how it would make sense for it to fail.

Comment: How would floor ever return something that's not an exact integer? For small doubles (epsilon << 1), all integral values can be represented, including floor(x). For big doubles (epsilon >> 1), only integral values can be represented, so floor(x)==x.

Comment: You are all talking about `floor` returning an integer, but none of its overloads returns an integer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor

Comment: @johnbakers: Where has anyone said that `floor` *does* return an integer (in terms of the return type)? The question is asking why it *doesn't* return an integer.

Comment: In the comments here, it is written `std::floor is meant to return an integer` and `How would floor ever return something that's not an exact integer?`

Comment: @johnbakers: "Return an integer" and "be declared to return `int` (or some other integer type)" aren't the same thing. It returns an integer, in that it returns a `double` whose value is an integer. Hence the part in my comment about "in terms of return type". Note that the documentation you referred to states: "If no errors occur, the largest integer value not greater than arg, that is ⌊arg⌋, is returned." So the comment is entirely in-keeping with that.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was the distinction between what is returned and what is declared to be returned that I found confusing.

Comment: @JonSkeet, probably Jesse Beder is referring to how an integer is represented as a double and what happens when casting to int. For e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695341/1047213.

Answer (score 19):

```
static_cast <int> (std::floor(x));
```

does pretty much what you want, yes. It gives you the nearest integer, rounded towards -infinity. At least as long as your input is in the range representable by ints.
I'm not sure what you mean by 'adding .5 and whatnot, but it won't have the same effect

And std::floor returns a double because that's the most general. Sometimes you might want to round off a float or double, but preserve the type. That is, round 1.3f to 1.0f, rather than to 1.

That'd be hard to do if std::floor returned an int. (or at least you'd have an extra unnecessary cast in there slowing things down).

If floor only performs the rounding itself, without changing the type, you can cast that to int if/when you need to.

Another reason is that the range of doubles is far greater than that of ints. It may not be possible to round all doubles to ints.

Comment: floor() rounds towards -infinity, not zero: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor.html

Answer (score 8):

The C++ standard says (4.9.1):

"An rvalue of a floating point type can be converted to an rvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type".

So if you are converting a double to an int, the number is within the range of int and the required rounding-up is toward zero, then it is enough to simply cast the number to int:

(int)x;

Comment: Truncation of the fraction part is not floor - the result is different for negative numbers.

Comment: I have clearly written "So if ... the required rounding-up is toward zero" to distinguish this case from "rounding-up toward -infinity". Floor is rounding toward -infinity, truncation - toward zero.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to deal with various numeric conditions and want to handle different types of conversions in a controlled way, then maybe you should look at the [Boost.NumericConversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html). This library allows to handle weird cases (like out-of-range, rounding, ranges, etc.)

Here is the example from the documentation:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/converter.hpp>

int main() {

    typedef boost::numeric::converter<int,double> Double2Int ;

    int x = Double2Int::convert(2.0);
    assert ( x == 2 );

    int y = Double2Int()(3.14); // As a function object.
    assert ( y == 3 ) ; // The default rounding is trunc.

    try
    {
        double m = boost::numeric::bounds<double>::highest();
        int z = Double2Int::convert(m); // By default throws positive_overflow()
    }
    catch ( boost::numeric::positive_overflow const& )
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the standard math library uses doubles but provides float versions as well.  std::floorf() is the single precision version of std::floor() if you'd prefer not to use doubles.

Edit: I've removed part of my previous answer.  I had stated that the floor was redundant when casting to int, but I forgot that this is only true for positive floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider std::llround(std::floor(x)) for doubles in the long long range.