# Image shaking when StretchDIBits partially

Tags: integer, shake, stretchdibits, approximate

I am using C++ GDI, StretchDIBits to draw images on DC.

Because the original Image is large, and high quality is needed. 
I use HAFTONE mode, to draw whole image on DC(zoom the image) seems time comsuming.

So I decide to draw partially using StretchDIBits.
But there is a serious problem about StretchDIBits.

I can only draw rect in integers to a region in integers(the width and height ,and top left point of x, y are all integers)

```
    ::SetStretchBltMode(hdc, HALFTONE);
    ::StretchDIBits(hdc,
        realDrawRect.left, 
        realDrawRect.top, 
        realDrawRect.right - realDrawRect.left, 
        realDrawRect.bottom - realDrawRect.top,
        left, 
        top, 
        width, 
        height,
        pImageDIB,
        pImageHead, 
        DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

if, the Image is 21 * 21 .
I now is drawing (5, 5, 7, 7) to DC, at  (20, 20, 60,60), the next time I wann to draw at (21, 20, 61, 60).
there is not corresponding location at original image. So I can only draw an approximation  rect to the DC.  Now the problem happening, the image is shaking!!

I am annoyed about that problem.
How can I avoid shaking?

Answer (score 0):

If the shaking comes from rounding the integer try rounding it down to nearest integer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605533/does-casting-to-an-int-after-stdfloor-guarantee-the-right-result).

Otherwise I would recommend that you switch to GDI+ which is much easier to work with. With GDI+ you can draw a bitmap with floating point precision. See documentation [Graphics::DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536039(VS.85).aspx).

I've switched from GDI to GDI+ in a couple of MFC Active-X projects and it's not hard at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal problem which I have faced when I used stretchDIBits in C++ as well as in C#. To overcome this problem, We had the functionality to correct the width and height of the image before calling stretchDIBits functionality:

```
if (m_currentImage.Width % 2 != 0) // check for odd number
{
     if (((m_currentImage.Width - 1) / 2) % 2 != 0)
           m_currentImage = m_currentImage.Resize(m_currentImage.Width - 3, m_currentImage.Height - 2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Linear);
     else
           m_currentImage = m_currentImage.Resize(m_currentImage.Width - 1, m_currentImage.Height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Linear);
}
else if ((m_currentImage.Width / 2) % 2 != 0) // else check fraction of width is odd number
     m_currentImage = m_currentImage.Resize(m_currentImage.Width - 2, m_currentImage.Height - 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Linear);
```