# Why do round() and ceil() not return an integer?

Tags: c++, c, casting, rounding

Once in a while, I find myself rounding some numbers, and I always have to cast the result to an integer:

```
int rounded = (int) floor(value);
```

Why do all rounding functions (`ceil()`, `floor()`) return a floating number, and not an integer? I find this pretty non-intuitive, and would love to have some explanations!

Comment: You could use your search skills and find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605533/does-casting-to-an-int-after-stdfloor-guarantee-the-right-result OR This may be helpful as well http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html

Comment: Good question - I had never thought to ask that

Comment: This duplicate managed to acquire an answer that is (IMHO) better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348180/why-doesnt-floor-return-an-integer

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The  integral  value  returned  by  these functions may be too large to store in an integer type (int, long,  etc.).   To  avoid  an  overflow, which  will  produce undefined results, an application should perform a range check on the returned value before assigning  it  to  an  integer type.

from the ceil(3) Linux man page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I accepted your because you were first ;) !

Answer (score 30):

That's because `float`'s range is wider than `int`'s. What would you expect to have if the value returned by these functions did not fit into an `int`? That would be undefined behaviour and you would be unable to check for that in your program.

Comment: There would not need to be any undefined behaviour - the functions *could* have been specified to return an error value in that case, just like strtol() does if the number to be converted doesn't fit into a long.  The reason is simply that the functions would be far less useful if they were restricted to the range of int.

Comment: @caf: let me disagree. Every time I use floor/ceil, I need to cast the value to int and it is  always such that no overflow occurs. This is the rule rather than the exception.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: It's not clear exactly what you're disagreeing with?

Comment: @caf: "the functions would be far less useful if they were restricted to the range of int".