# __float128 rounding

Tags: c++, gcc, rounding

How can I round __float128 in C++ to get __int128? I found some rounding functions in quadmath.h but their result is long long or something even shorter or integer stored in __float128. This question isn't duplicate of [Why do round() and ceil() not return an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253670/why-do-round-and-ceil-not-return-an-integer) because I use 128-bit numbers and casting doesn't work for them.

Comment: max of `__int128` is `2^127 + 1` which is much smaller than some big `__float128`, hence `round(__float128)` need to return a `__float128`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do round() and ceil() not return an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253670/why-do-round-and-ceil-not-return-an-integer)

Comment: But I need the result to be __int128 and I will use it only for __float128, which can be also represented as __int128. In that linked question, the solution is cast but it doesn't work for 128-bit numbers and it always returns 0.

Comment: I can't try it, but just assigning one to the other doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, actually it works but I had another error in my program, so it seemed like the assignment or casting has always 0 as a result. Thanks for finding this error even if it is another problem than I thought.

Comment: @MartinSchmied: Then I'd suggest, you either modify the question accordingly or delete it altogether

Comment: `__float128` can represent a float up to ≈ 1.1897 × 10^4932 which isn't representable by `__int128` which is in range `-(2^128)` (or `-2^127 -1` in some system) to `2^127+1`. This question is exactly duplicate with my suggestion. You need to use `roundf128` than check if that value bigger than or equal with `2^128` and `-(2^128)`, if ok than make a cast

Answer (score 0):

`__int128` can only represent an integer which is in range -2<sup>128</sup> (or -2<sup>127</sup> - 1 in some system) to 2<sup>127</sup> + 1.

`__float128` can represent a float up to 2<sup>16384</sup> - 2<sup>16271</sup> ≈ 1.1897 × 10<sup>4932</sup> which isn much bigger than `__int128`.

You need to:

- use `roundq` to get the rounded `__float128` than.
- check if that value stays in range [-2<sup>128</sup>, 2<sup>128</sup>], these numbers are 1 outside the limit of `__int128` and both of them can be represented correctly by a float because they're a power of 2.
- if it is in that range, make a cast to `__int128`

Alternately, from [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/Math-Library-Routines.html#Math-Library-Routines) you can use `llroundq`: round to nearest integer value away from zero. But in this case, quote from libquadmath source code:

```
  else
    {
      /* The number is too large.  It is left implementation defined
     what happens.  */
      return (long long int) x;
    }
```