# How to raise an int or long to a power in C++

Tags: c++, pow

Trivial question: I am just wondering, if one wants to raise an int or a long to the power of another int or long, does

```
(long)std::pow((double)a,(double)b)
```

suffice, or do I need

```
(long)(0.5 + std::pow((double)a,(double)b))
```

?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two considerations. The first is roundoff due to inexactness of floating point representations; this won't be a problem in this case, because integers are perfectly representable as long as the number of bits is less than the bits of significand in the floating point. If `long` is 32 bits and `double` significand is 53 bits, as it usually is, there won't be a problem.

The second consideration is the accuracy of the `pow` function itself. If there's any possibility that it will come out lower than the actual value, adding 0.5 to round the result is the only way to ensure the proper result.

The expected result of your `pow` will always be an integer, so there's no harm in adding 0.5. I'd recommend that version.

Comment: Great answer. I guess it is best not to assume anything about the accuracy of the `pow` function and just use v2.

Comment: Any ideas or reasons there isn't an integer form of `pow` in the standard library?

Comment: @Thomas, just guessing - a combination of not needing it very often and `pow` being a good enough substitute.

Answer (score 3):

You should write your own function. That way you can handle overflow yourself, and you don't have to worry about rounding errors.

But of the two I would use the second.

Answer (score 3):

The second example may be more suitable as it rounds the result off to the nearest integer rather than truncates it.

Comment: Remember that (int)0.999 = 0 but (int)(0.999+0.5) = 1

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a loop. There can't be more than 31/63 integer multiplications without overflow anyway.

Comment: One more own function in the code base I guess. Plus efficiency. But I agree that it is an option.

Comment: Here is an implementation with only 5/6 multiplications. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int/101613#101613

Answer (score 1):

First one would be sufficient but you need to check the result double value before casting since it can be pretty larger than long's max.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is valid. It would be best to use a `static_cast<>()` instead of a c-style cast for clarity however. The second example you posted would give an incorrect result for small values and is superfluous.

Comment: When would the second example yield incorrect results? And couldn't it happen in the first example that say 3 ^ 3 becomes 8.9999999999 and in the cast becomes 8? I don't expect this to happen for small numbers but once numbers become large, is this not a possibility?

Comment: @myself: It would give wrong results for -ve a and odd b of course, but apart from that?

Comment: If you have a negative exponent or compute a power where the result is less than 1. Considering the result will be cast back to an integer value that's going to be a problem anyway.

Comment: @Ephphatha: Less than 1 (and not 0) can't happen with ints or longs.

Comment: @john: According to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605533/does-casting-to-an-int-after-stdfloor-guarantee-the-right-result) truncating is to neg infinity, not zero. So say -2 to 3, would be -7.9999 or -8.0001, becomes -7.5 becomes -8.

Comment: @Cookie: std::floor truncates to negative infinity. You used a cast, which truncates to zero.

Comment: @john: I see. In that case a std::floor might be more appropriate?

Comment: @Cookie: I think so, but don't take my word for it, write some test code and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to do:

```
static_cast<long>(std::pow(static_cast<double>(a), b));
```

You should realise that this will overflow on large values of b.