# C++: How to round a double to an int?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

I have a double (call it x), meant to be 55 but in actuality stored as 54.999999999999943157 which I just realised.

So when I do

```
double x = 54.999999999999943157;
int y = (int) x;
```

y = 54 instead of 55!

This puzzled me for a long time. How do I get it to correctly round?

Comment: You could add 0.5 to the number and then do your cast to let it truncate to an int. Do you need to round negative numbers?

Comment: You can use this preprocessor definition: `#define ROUND_2_INT(f) ((int)(f >= 0.0 ? (f + 0.5) : (f - 0.5)))`

Comment: Actually 54.999999999999943157 is 8 ULPs below _exactly representable_ 55 if by `double` you mean binary64 from IEEE 754. So this is not how 55 is actually stored, it's the consequence of how imprecise your calculation of it was.

Comment: Adding +0.5 to a negative input before turning it into an int will give the wrong answer.  The correct quick-and-dirty way is to test the input sign for <0, and then SUBTRACT 0.5 from the negative inputs before turning them into an int.  Most of the following answers do not explain this properly.  Note high-accuracy procedures should use the new slower "round()" function.

Comment: See also [Convert double to int in C++ without round down errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374153/convert-double-to-int-in-c-without-round-down-errors).

Comment: For me, the program to below prints "55". Am I doing something differently than you?

`#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float x = 55;
    int y = (int) x;
    cout << y;
}`

Comment: @plafratt It may be possible that your system's implementation of `float` is such that `float x = 55` is stored as a value slightly greater than `55` instead. In this case `(int) x` would seem to 'round down' correctly to `55`, and not `54`, as in my case.

Comment: Oh ok. For reference, the code below gives this output: "55 55.00000000000000000000". `#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float x = 55;
    int y = (int) x;
    cout << y << " " << fixed << setprecision(20) << x << "\n";
}`

Changing the "float x = 55;" to "float x = 55.1;" gives me the output "55 55.09999847412109375000"

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rbd/papers/cmj-float-to-int.html

Comment: the question in not equivalent to referenced question as it asking for type conversion as well

Answer (score 175, accepted):

add 0.5 before casting (if x > 0) or subtract 0.5 (if x < 0), because the compiler will always truncate.

```
float x = 55; // stored as 54.999999...
x = x + 0.5 - (x<0); // x is now 55.499999...
int y = (int)x; // truncated to 55
```

C++11 also introduces [std::round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), which likely uses a similar logic of adding 0.5 to |x| under the hood (see the link if interested) but is obviously more robust.

A follow up question might be *why* the float isn't stored as exactly 55. For an explanation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) stackoverflow answer.

Comment: it would work equally as well with just int y=x+0.5; though right?

Comment: I wouldn't use the phrase "round down", because that could be interpreted as rounding `-0.5` to `-1`.

Comment: As @Verax mentioned, this does not work for negative numbers as cast truncates toward 0. You may use the same logic with 'floor' instead as it truncates towards -infinity.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It will give you wrong answer if the number is negative.

Comment: @Moritz; Oh sorry, I will upvote you. My apologies.

Comment: -1 this is a hacky solution at best. zik's answer is much better as it uses a library function: works on negative numbers, doesn't do weird casting and it's explicit about it's intention.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson ``ceil()``/``floor()`` also adds another level to the call stack (although I suspect that a modern compiler will inline it for you,) makes you include a library header and generally introduces more overhead. I don't think one is necessarily worse than the other without knowing what the OP is trying to accomplish. Also, I don't think casting from floating-point to int explicitly is that "weird"...whether you see it or not, that type conversion has to happen somewhere along the line :)

Comment: @Moritz One can perform rounding and still return a double. Regardless, the point here is that the code is not explicit about what sort of casting it does. Does it take floor, ceil, rounds it, or does it just interpret the bits at the memory location referenced by the double as ints? Writing the code like this needlessly makes the reader remember what the conversion rules are. I agree that there are places where this code makes sense, but imagine someone googles "how to round c++" and ends on this page. IMO, the best answer for that situation is the one below.

Comment: I prefer positive numbers

Comment: What do you mean by `stored as stored as 54.999999...`? `55` is exactly representable in binary32 from IEEE 754. Its representation is 0x425c0000. As you can see, it's _more than exact_: It has plenty of digits to store some fractional part you add to it. And it's especially true of `0.5`, which is a power of two.

Comment: This is inaccurate & possibly slow. See clang-tidy for an explanation : http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/misc-incorrect-roundings.html

Comment: @ACyclic unfortunately, the link you provided is dead.

Comment: @Pac0 Updated link on why this is inaccurate : http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.2/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/misc-incorrect-roundings.html

Comment: @ACyclic That link just states it's bad but doesn't provide any suggestions to the problem.

Answer (score 73):

Casting is not a mathematical operation and doesn't behave as such.  Try

```
int y = (int)round(x);
```

Comment: The cast is unnecessary; the result will be implicitly converted to `int`.

Comment: I could never remember the C type promotion rules and I think that it doesn't hurt to state type casts explicitly everywhere, them being such a sticky issue.

Comment: What library is `round` part of? AFAIK it's not in the C++ standard library. `ceil` and `floor` are available.

Comment: @Steve #include <math.h>, STANDARDS
     The round() , lround() , and llround() functions conform to ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E).

Comment: @MK - Well that's actually C not C++ right? I referred to this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/

Comment: @SteveFallows: It exists in C++11.

Comment: @MK.: It's not a promotion, it's just an implicit conversion.  An assignment, initialization, or parameter passing will implicitly convert any numeric type to any other numeric type.  Unnecessary casts can be harmful.  For example, `n = (int)round(x);` looks ok -- but what if `n` is of type `long`?

Comment: In both C99 and C++11, ```double round  (double x);``` Therefore, the cast is indeed necessary. Link:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/

Comment: if you use `std::round(double arg)` cast is necessary; but if you use `std::lround(double arg)` cast is not needed

Answer (score 9):

Casting to an `int` truncates the value. Adding `0.5` causes it to do proper rounding.

```
int y = (int)(x + 0.5);
```

Comment: not valid for negative numbers, as mentioned in one of the comments above. Can use 'floor' instead of cast if you are doing this.

Answer (score 5):

It is worth noting that what you're doing isn't rounding, it's casting. Casting using `(int) x` truncates the decimal value of `x`. As in your example, if `x = 3.9995`, the `.9995` gets truncated and `x = 3`.

As proposed by many others, one solution is to add `0.5` to `x`, and then cast.

Comment: Thank you, actually I only just realised I even need to round (I am using only integers in my program)

Answer (score -10):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x=54.999999999999943157;
    int y=ceil(x);//The ceil() function returns the smallest integer no less than x
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This forces numbers up though... 54.000000000000001 will become 55.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, right - which means this answer is wrong.