# Result of casting double to int is wrong

Tags: c++, casting, floating-accuracy

There seems to be some kind of obscure rounding error when I run the following code:

```
int roundedTotal = (int)(PriorityJob * 100.0);
```

Initially `PriorityJob = 1.4` and `roundedTotal` is undefined. Evaluating `PriorityJob * 100.0` at that point gives `140`. Afterwards `roundedTotal = 139`.

Apparently, 140.0 is being interpreted as 139.99999. Is this a deficiency in the floating point engine? I have never seen anything like it.

Comment: 1.4 does not exist as a float. In fact, there's an infinite number of numbers even between 1.0 and 2.0 that cannot be represented as a float, 1.4 is one of them. So it gets stored as an approximation of 1.4 , as 1.3999999999999999

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It seems like such a simple operation. Why should it fail like that?

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @MichaelSandler: Because a binary floating point format can't represent most decimal fractions exactly, so you have to expect rounding errors.

Comment: `roundTotal` is never undefined, since you initialize it!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Apparently, he hasn't, so why bother to ask? That's why he's here. Not?

Comment: @nos Of course! Thank you. An elementary oversight on my part. 1.4 is not neatly represented in binary. Care to answer?

Comment: @MichaelSandler it doesn't fail. Casting (especially in old style C-manner) means "I know, it is not the right thing, what I'm doing, but I know all side-effects of this operation and want exactly this result." So why don't you use rounding? e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695329/c-how-to-round-a-double-to-an-int

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz - the cast is irrelevant here; it just tells the compiler to do what it would do anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just about every modern computer uses a [binary representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for floating-point numbers.

Just as `1/3 = 0.33333333...` can't be represented exactly as a decimal fraction, so `1/10` (and hence most non-integer decimal values, including `1.4`) can't be represented exactly as a binary fraction. It will instead be represented by the nearest representable value, which may be slightly more or less than the "true" value.

You might want to round to the nearest integer instead: `(int)(PriorityJob * 100.0 + 0.5)`

Comment: And the difference in the displayed values comes up because `std::cout << PriorityJob * 100.0` rounds, while `int roundTotal = PriorityJob * 100.0` drops the fractional part.