# Convert double to int?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, double

My code is below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double f = 18.40;
    printf("%d\n", (int)(10 * f));

    return 0;
}
```

The result is 184 in VC6.0, while the result in Codeblock is 183. Why?

Comment: I just ran this on CodeBlocks and got `184` as the result.

Comment: What compiler are you using with CodeBlock?

Comment: @mathk my compiler is g++

Comment: @mathk is there any difference between gcc and g++ when converting float to int?

Comment: Add `0.5` every times you need to round a double to an integer :   `(int)((10. * f)+0.5)` will work with all compilers.

Comment: @Charles0429 gcc and g++ are the same things apart from some option set by default with g++. So there is no difference for float to int conversion. But it might have some difference between VC6 and gcc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for this is that GCC tries to make the code backward compatible with older architectures of the CPU as much as possible, while MSVC tries to take advantage of the newer futures of the architecture.

The code generated by MSVC multiplies the two numbers, 10.0 × 18.40:

```
.text:00401006 fld     ds:dbl_40D168
.text:0040100C fstp    [ebp+var_8]
.text:0040100F fld     ds:dbl_40D160
.text:00401015 fmul    [ebp+var_8]
.text:00401018 call    __ftol2_sse
```

and then call a function named `__ftol2_sse`, inside this function it converts the result to integer using some instruction named `cvttsd2si`:

```
.text:00401189 push    ebp
.text:0040118A mov     ebp, esp
.text:0040118C sub     esp, 8
.text:0040118F and     esp, 0FFFFFFF8h
.text:00401192 fstp    [esp+0Ch+var_C]
.text:00401195 cvttsd2si eax, [esp+0Ch+var_C]
.text:0040119A leave
.text:0040119B retn
```

This instruction, `cvttsd2si`, is according to this [page](http://www.asmpedia.org/index.php?title=CVTTSD2SI):

> Convert scalar double-precision floating-point value (with truncation)
>   to signed doubleword of quadword integer (SSE2)

it basically converts the double into integer. This instruction is part of instruction set called [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sse2) which is introduced with Intel Pentium 4.

GCC doesn't uses this instructions set by default and tries to do it with the available instructions from i386:

```
fldl   0x28(%esp)
fldl   0x403070
fmulp  %st,%st(1)
fnstcw 0x1e(%esp)
mov    0x1e(%esp),%ax
mov    $0xc,%ah
mov    %ax,0x1c(%esp)
fldcw  0x1c(%esp)
fistpl 0x18(%esp)
fldcw  0x1e(%esp)
mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
movl   $0x403068,(%esp)
call   0x401b44 <printf>
mov    $0x0,%eax
```

if you want GCC to use `cvttsd2si` you need to tell it to use the futures available from SSE2 by compiling with the flag `-msse2`, but also this means that some people who still using older computers won't be able to run this program. See here [Intel 386 and AMD x86-64 Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) for more options.

So after compiling with `-msse2` it will use `cvttsd2si` to convert the result to 32 bit integer:

```
0x004013ac <+32>:    movsd  0x18(%esp),%xmm1
0x004013b2 <+38>:    movsd  0x403070,%xmm0
0x004013ba <+46>:    mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
0x004013be <+50>:    cvttsd2si %xmm0,%eax
0x004013c2 <+54>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x004013c6 <+58>:    movl   $0x403068,(%esp)
0x004013cd <+65>:    call   0x401b30 <printf>
0x004013d2 <+70>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
```

now both MSVC and GCC should give the same number:

```
> type test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double f = 18.40;
    printf("%d\n", (int) (10.0  * f));

    return 0;
}
> gcc -Wall test.c -o gcctest.exe -msse2
> cl test.c /W3 /link /out:msvctest.exe
> gcctest.exe
184
> msvctest.exe
184
>
```

Answer (score 3):

The point is, that `0.4` is `2/5` . Fractions with anything but a power of two in the denominator are not exactly representable in floating point numbers, much like 1/3 is not exactly representable as a decimal number. Thus, your compiler has to choose a nearby, representable number, with the result that `10*18.4` is not precisely `184`, but `183.999`...

Now, everything depends on the rounding mode employed when your float is converted to an integer. With **round to nearest** or **round to infinity**, you get `184`, with **round to zero** or **round to minus infinity** you get `183`.

Comment: is there any difference between gcc and g++ when converting float to int?

Comment: @Charles0429 Sorry, I don't know about any compiler specifics, I only know about the details of the floating point format and the way floating point calculations are performed by the CPU. But, maybe someone else knows?

Comment: correct answer +1 :) round towards 0 and round towards - infinity should be true regardless of the cases .

Comment: Assuming the compiler succeeded to constant-fold the computation here, it would be interesting to complicate the test program to the point where it would be forced to compute it at runtime. In particular, you could read the number 10 from stdin or a command line argument.

Comment: This answer falsely states that “everything” depends on the rounding mode used when converting `float` to `int`. The rounding is fixed by the C standard; it is round-toward-zero. The result depends on the value obtained when the source text `18.4` is converted to floating-point and multiplied by 10.

Answer (score 2):

Codeblocks compiler has probably something like 18.39999999999 as the floating point value. I think you should round if you want a consistent result.

Comment: Could you tell what's the difference between codeblock and vc6.0?Does the float type not same in each compiler?

Comment: It's based on the selected compiler. Code:Blocks supports probably every c compiler on this planet. I assume you have the default one which is g++. I'm not sure what it does with floating points but in general never (!) assume that two floating points are exactly the same even if the are calculated the same way.

Comment: is there any difference between gcc and g++ when converting float to int?

Comment: It is very bad practice to depend on the compiler for something like this. Please round your value. The best way to do this is descriped in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695329/c-how-to-round-a-double-to-an-int

Answer (score 1):

Floating point calculations are implemented differently by different compilers and different architectures. Even the same compiler can have different modes of operation that will yield different results.

For example, if I take your program and my installation of gcc (MinGW, 4.6.2) and compile like this:

```
gcc main.c
```

then the output is, as your report, 183.

However, if I compile like this:

```
gcc main.c -ffloat-store
```

then the output is 184.

If you really want to understand the differences you need to specify precise compiler versions, and specify which options you are passing to the compiler.

More fundamentally, you should be aware that the value `18.4` cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point value. The [closest representable double precision value to `18.4`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=18.4) is:

```
18.39999 99999 99998 57891 45284 79799 62825 77514 64843 75
```

So I suspect that you are reasoning that the correct output from your program is `184`. But I suspect that reasoning is flawed and fails to account for representability, rounding, etc. issues.