# C convert floating point to int

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I'm using **C** (not C++).

I need to convert a float number into an `int`. I do not want to round to the the nearest number, I simply want to eliminate what is after the integer part. Something like

```
4.9 -> 4.9 -> 4
```

Comment: Enough about the haircut - it is just a cast that you require

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “convert an `int` to a binary number”—`int` already _is_ binary… Or do you mean to convert it to a string of the binary representation, e.g. convert `14` to `"1110"`. Either way: How did the floating point numbers get into that conversion?

Comment: After reading User 3195614's answer: Maybe the confusion comes from integer division evaluating to integers? `5 / 2` evaluates to `2` in C, not to `2.5`.

Comment: anything that has a decimal point is going to be handled as float or larger.  The way to get the value is either the lib function int floor(float) or (for roundingup) int ceil(float).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
my_var = (int)my_var;
```

As simple as that. 
Basically you don't need it if the variable is int.

Comment: Make sure you do what you want/should for negative and large numbers. Things may be more complicated. If the floats are positive and smaller than the maximum integer on your platform, you ara safe.

Comment: This is nice, but it is also undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 17):

Use in C

```
int C = var_in_float;
```

They will convert implicit

Answer (score 15):

If you want to round it to lower, just cast it.

```
float my_float = 42.8f;
int my_int;
my_int = (int)my_float;          // => my_int=42
```

For other purpose, if you want to round it to nearest, you can make a little function or a define like this:

```
#define FLOAT_TO_INT(x) ((x)>=0?(int)((x)+0.5):(int)((x)-0.5))

float my_float = 42.8f;
int my_int;
my_int = FLOAT_TO_INT(my_float); // => my_int=43
```

Be careful, ideally you should verify float is between INT_MIN and INT_MAX before casting it.

Comment: Using Macros with logic is not incredibly smart, as people tend to view them as functions. For example if you were to `FLOAT_TO_INT(rand())` it would behave weird, better to make it a function

Comment: regarding: `#define FLOAT_TO_INT(x) ((x)>=0?(int)((x)+0.5):(int)((x)-0.5))`  Those literals `0.5` is a `double` You really want `float`.  Suggest: `#define FLOAT_TO_INT(x) ((x)>=0.0f?(int)((x)+0.5f):(int)((x)-0.5f))

Comment: " round it to lower" is incorrect/unclear for negative values.  `(int)` truncates the fraction.

Comment: @user3629249 `(x)+0.5f` can give incorrect rounded results when the sum is inexact.  `(x)+0.5` avoids this by using wider `double` math.  IAC `lroundf()`, `roundf()`  is better.

Answer (score 6):

```
double a = 100.3;
printf("%f %d\n", a, (int)(a* 10.0));

Output Cygwin 100.3 1003
Output MinGW: 100.3 1002
```

Using (int) to convert double to int seems not to be fail-safe

You can find more about that here: [Convert double to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587452/convert-double-to-int)

Comment: unfortunately, the question is about converting `float` to `int`, not `double` to `int`

Comment: @user3629249 Same issue applies with `float`, yet a `float` only example would be better here.

Answer (score 0):

Good guestion! -- where I have not yet found a satisfying answer for my case,
the answer I provide here works for me, but may not be future proof...

If one uses gcc (clang?) and have `-Werror` and -`Wbad-function-cast` defined,

```
int val = (int)pow(10,9);
```

will result:

`error: cast from function call of type 'double' to non-matching type 'int' [-Werror=bad-function-cast]`

(for a good reason, overflow and where values are rounded needs to be thought out)

EDIT: 2020-08-30: So, my use case casting the value from function returning double to int, and chose pow() to represent that in place
of a private function somewhere. Then I sidestepped thinking pow() more.
(See comments more why pow() used below could be problematic...).

After properly thought out (that parameters to pow() are good), `int val = pow(10,9);` seems to work with gcc 9.2 x86-64 ...

but note:

```
printf("%d\n", pow(10,4));
```

may output e.g.

```
-1121380856
```

(did for me) where

```
int i = pow(10,4); printf("%d\n", i);
```

printed

```
10000
```

in one particular case I tried.

Comment: pow returns a double, that's why you can't print it using `%d`. And using pow for that purpose is wrong because it may return incorrect results for integers. Use 1e4 instead to get 10^4. See [Why does gcc compiler output pow(10,2) as 99 not 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25474351/995714), [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714), [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714)

Comment: OOh, this (int)14e was great. Is it safe? 1e4 w/o casting has type 'double' (as the pow() case)

Comment: Lost change to edit above comment more -- just recently I had use case for `1e6`, but (as usual) I used `printf("%d\n", 1e6);` to test it out and got weird results. if `const int million = 1e6` is found safe I start using such a format.

Comment: `1e6` relies on the compiler to make a quality `double` to `int` conversion.  Less likely a problem than `pow()`, yet I see no C spec guaranteeing the best answer.  Alternatives to `(int)1e6`: [Why write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40633059/2410359) and [why not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

Comment: yes `pow()` is bad, compared to `10e4` in this example (have to fix, with edit commit). I wondered why that `10e4` is `double` not `int`, then tried `1.12e1` and `12e-3` to understand.