# Overloaded Operator Type Error

Tags: c++, function, class, operator-overloading, operators

I have created a `Money` class that uses the following function to convert `Money` to a percent of its value. I am trying to create an overloaded operator to accomplish the same, however I get `Error: Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type` for `scaledCents` in the overloaded operator below; they are otherwise identical. How can this be amended? Thanks in advance.

```
Money Money::percent(const Money& amount, double percentage) const {
    int amountToCents = amount.getCents() + amount.getDollars() * 100;
    double pScaledMoney = amountToCents * percentage;
    int scaledDollars = abs((round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) / 100);
    int scaledCents = abs((round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) % 100);
    if (pScaledMoney < 0) {
        scaledDollars = -scaledDollars;
        scaledCents = -scaledCents;
    }
    return Money(scaledDollars, scaledCents);
}
```

Overloaded operator:

```
const Money operator %(const Money& amount, double percentage) {
    int amountToCents = amount.getCents() + amount.getDollars() * 100;
    double pScaledMoney = amountToCents * percentage;
    int scaledDollars = abs((round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) / 100);
    int scaledCents = abs((round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) % 100);
    if (pScaledMoney < 0) {
        scaledDollars = -scaledDollars;
        scaledCents = -scaledCents;
    }
    return Money(scaledDollars, scaledCents);
}
```

Comment: Why returning a `const Money` ?

Comment: I wonder if your operator is in-class or out-of-class?

Comment: @jnbrq     `friend const Money operator %(const Money& amount, double percentage);` is public inside the class. It's definition is outside.

Comment: OK. I was just thinking that the error is just wrong definition of the operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value of `round()` has floating point type. The numerical operator `%` cannot be used with doubles or floats:

```
// error
(round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) % 100
// fixed
((int)round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))) % 100
```

---

If you are concerned about loss of precions it is better to use version of `round` function that returns integer to avoid issues like [C++: How to round a double to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695329/c-how-to-round-a-double-to-an-int) and 
http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1

C99 and C++11 have the exact function that you need:

```
long int lround (double x);
```

---

*Other code style issues (not related to the error)*

Your two functions do not use any private members of Money, so none of them should be a friend or a class memeber. Both can be defined out of class.

It does not make sense to return `const Money` from a function if you return a new object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why is it not required in my original function? Concerned about best practice and data loss.

Comment: @Austin There is the same bug in both functions. It should throw error in both. Is it possible that `Money::percent` is not compiled or compilation was interrupted by the error in `operator%`?

Comment: The original compiles with no errors. The overloaded example will not compile. So they cannot be run together as is. `((int)round(fabs(pScaledMoney / 100))` used for `scaledCents` will compile with a warning for `scaledDollars`. No errors/warnings when applied to both.

Comment: @Austin Actually it is not a compiler error. This messages comes from IntelliSense before compilation. It is possible that IntelliSense treats member functions and non members in a differnt way or it does not like operators :-) You can check that if you also move `percent()` out of the class.

Comment: It was flagged in the same way after moving it outside the class. Makes (Intelli)sense now. I will accept your answer shortly (would be good to note the last comment into it). Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Austin I updated the answer by important remark about proper rounding of floating point numbers to integers. Also make sure that `abs` that you are using returns integer number (it should be from `cstdlib` instead of `cmath`).