# getting invalid errors for array type

Tags: c++

getting an invalid array type in the for loop not allowing me to fill the array sivalues. it wont poulate the array with x

```
int main () {
    double a,b,increment,para;
    int N;
    cout<< "enter values for (a,b,N)";
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    cin>>N;
    increment= (b-a)/(N-1);
    double sivalues[N];
    for (double x=a;x<=b;x+=increment){
        sivalues[x]=si(x);
        cout<<"si("<<x<<") = "<< sivalues[x];
    }

    system("PAUSE"); return 0;

}
```

Comment: Unless I'm blind, `increment` is never initialized, which might be *a* problem.

Comment: And what's the exact error?

Comment: i updated the code

Answer (score 2):

When you write `sivalues[x]`, you are using a `double` as an array index. This is not valid, as it would make no sense to get the 2.5th element of an array, for instance. You would therefore need to cast your `double` into a `int`.

You could use the default cast (for example : `sivalues[int(x)]=si(x);`. Do note that this cast does not round, so if x is 5.99, it will still be converted to 5 (see [C++: How to round a double to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695329/c-how-to-round-a-double-to-an-int))