# Why this conversion to int gives a false result

Tags: c++

I found a bug in my program with some specific values. The conversion to `int` is wrong. The results should be 201 but the results is 200. Why it is wrong and how to safely convert to `int`?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main() 
 {
    double y = 591860.6;
    double x = 591820.4;
    double r = 0.2;
    cout << (y - x) / r << " " << (int)((y - x) / r) << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

> 201 200

I found a workaround but yet I don't understand why it works

```
(int)(float)((y - x) / r)
```

> 201 201

Comment: Your first `201` is not really 201.  It's `200.9999999997672` and `cout` rounds it. Use `std::setprecision(16)` when debuging using `cout`, or use your debugger to see the real value.

Comment: Well actually I understand the problem and I know it comes from floating point precision. But how can I get an integer in this case? With `round`?

Comment: `round` seems like a good choice

Comment: Using `(int)` as cast does not round, it just throws everything away after the decimal point [C++: How to round a double to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695329/c-how-to-round-a-double-to-an-int)

Comment: `round` sounds like what you want.  There is also `floor` and `ceil` but you'd need to know which one to use which round does for you. You just have to decide if you'd rather have rounding or truncation as that is a big difference.

Comment: Will use `round` thanks.

Comment: You should calculate `(y - x)` once and store into a temporary `const` variable.

Comment: std::cout << "rounded value = " << std::round((y - x) / r) << '\n';