# Why is using an int to round this calculation to one decimal place not working?

Tags: c++, rounding

```
#iclude <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double speed = 5;
    int temp = -5;
    int windChill;
    double roundedWindChill;

    windChill = ((35.74 + (0.6215 * temp) - (35.75 * pow(speed, 0.16)) + (0.4275 * temp *   (pow(speed0.16)))) * 10.0) + 0.5;
    roundedWindChill = windChill / 10.0;
        cout << roundedWindChill;
}
```

When I run this I get `16.3`, however I should be getting 16.4 because the answer with an additional figure would be `16.37`. Not sure why this is not rounding.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would division by 10 perform rounding?

Comment: Float-to-integer conversion doesn't round. It truncates. Add 0.5 to round.

Comment: Converting floating point to `int` always rounds towards zero.  It doesn't round to the nearest integer.   Either add `0.5`  or (since C++11) use `std::round()` or `std::lround()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++: How to round a double to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695329/c-how-to-round-a-double-to-an-int)

Comment: The problem is a *bit* more subtle than some of the above comments suggest. The loss of precision occurs in the line before the division by 10: that gives an integer result of -163, so there is no possibility of recovering the lost `7` after that point.

Comment: @AdrianMole *"The problem is a bit more subtle than some of the above comments suggest."* -- also suggested by the choice of the name `roundedWindChill`. ;) If the OP had chosen more accurate names for the variables, maybe the first comment would not have been made.

Comment: It should be noted that the cute `x+.5` does not round negative numbers correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Due to integer division rules in C++, the result is truncated towards zero.

Suppose we have the following code:

```
int a = 8;
int b = 3;
int c = a / b;
```

The value would be 2.

In your code, the expression windChill / 10.0 is performing such division, which discards any decimal places and rounds the result down to the nearest integer.

To fix this, use `std::round()` from the `<cmath>` library to round *windChill* **before** dividing by 10.0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double speed = 5;
    int temp = -5;
    int windChill;
    double roundedWindChill;

    windChill = round((35.74 + (0.6215 * temp) - (35.75 * pow(speed, 0.16)) + (0.4275 * temp * (pow(speed,0.16)))) * 10.0);
    roundedWindChill = windChill / 10.0;
    cout << roundedWindChill;
}
```

Comment: it'd be better to not round at all and just print to the required precision

Comment: One minor correction: the number is truncated period. There is no "truncation towards zero". Try with a negative number.